# using nstimer in viewcontroller

Tags: iphone

I have a scenario where I need to start/stop a timer on a button click. I may move from the page and come back again but the timer should be running. For this purpose I am stoping and releasing it in viewWillDisappear method and restarting it on the basis of a condition in viewWillAppear. But It is not getting started again. Following is my code:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
if([timerInterval isValid]) {
    [timerInterval invalidate];
    //[timerInterval release];
    timerInterval = nil;
}
```

}

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
HealthyBabyAppDelegate *appDel = (HealthyBabyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[appDel changeBackground]]];
if(appDel.contractionDutation>0) {
    //if(timerInterval==nil)
    timerInterval = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(printInterval) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

}

```
-(IBAction)Contraction:(id)sender {
HealthyBabyAppDelegate *appDel = (HealthyBabyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if([(UIButton*)sender tag]==2) {//stop the contrction
    [(UIButton*)sender setTag:1];
    [(UIButton*)sender setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [appDel startContractionTimer:FALSE];
    [timerInterval invalidate];
    //timerInterval = nil;
}
else {//start the contraction, 2 means contraction is running
    [(UIButton*)sender setTag:2];
    [(UIButton*)sender setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [appDel startContractionTimer:TRUE];
    ([[tblContractionDetail cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] textLabel]).text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Start Time: %@",appDel.contractionStartTime];
    timerInterval = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(printInterval) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

}

```
Contraction method will stop/delete the timer.
```

Thanks
Pankaj

Comment: Are you sure viewWillAppear is actually being called again?

Comment: yes I have checked it with debugger....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSTimer should not be released. It will release itself by triggering `invalidate` remove the line `timerInterval = nil;` and try it again. The other thing I have noticed myself: a timer should always be created by MainThread otherwise it will not start executing.

//EDIT: try this code to start it again:

```
// inside your function    
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startUpdate) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];


-(void)startUpdate {
    updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 
                target:self 
                selector:@selector(doSomething) 
                userInfo:nil 
                repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by calling it from Main Thread? do yo mean calling it from app delegate?

Comment: If you don't know the difference between MainThread and background thread then you probably using only the MainThread. (multithreading) for completeness the call would be [self performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:]

Comment: jep maybe my answer was not clear enough I doesn't wanted to say he have to remove the line. I'm currently not at my lab and couldn't test it so it was a suggestion to set it nil, maybe helps ^^